# Can I apply a css class based on the $index and the length of an ng-repeat object?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I hope this hasn't been answered anywhere else. I am trying to create a rule with `ng-class` that:

- displays `firstTagClass` if the item is `$first` in the repeater index
- is not displayed when the item is the only item in the repeater
- that doesn't use `scope.objects.length` (because scope.objects is not an array but an object in this specific case).

**USE CASE**

Can be a great starting point to crop avatar pictures and hold them in the same container.

**SO FAR...**

I completed the first and third objectives but I am stuck with the second. I tried to add a second condition `!$last` but it doesn't work.

```
<div 
  ng-repeat="object in objects" 
  ng-if="$index < 4 && object.id !== me.id" 
  ng-class="{firstTagClass: $first && !$last}">
</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve all of my goals through `ng-class` or should I build a custom directive?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Hadrien

**UPDATE**

I am adding a Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYaBjW

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer making use of a directive. You can check the solution by removing the 3rd object in $scope.objects here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEOopR

**HTML**

I added the `block-style` directive and used the `class` attribute instead of `ng-class` since I chose to use `element.removeClass()` in my `link` function. It seemed more logical to remove a class because my intention was to make it the exception and not the rule.

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects"
     class="firstTagClass"
     ng-if="$index < 4 && object.id !== me.id"
     position="{{index}}"
     block-style>
  {{object.id}}
</div>
```

**JS**

The details of the `blockStyle` directive:

```
restrict: 'A',
link: function(scope, el, attrs){
  var objects = scope.objects;
  var me = scope.me;
  var userCount = Object.keys(objects).length;
  var position = parseInt(attrs.position);

  //assign hasMe attribute for objects collection with me object
  if(objects){
    for(var prop in objects){
      if(objects[prop].id === me.id){
        objects.hasMe = true;
      }
    }
  }

  //handle particular case of 1 object displayed
  if(userCount < 2 || userCount < 3 && objects.hasMe === true){
    el.removeClass('firstTagClass');
  }else if(position > 0){
    el.removeClass('firstTagClass');
  }  
} // end of link function
```